# Simple test RFI tests for fluorescent bulb replacement

Tags: lighting

I am interested in testing RFI originating from [LED T8 replacement bulbs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JOH9PP0), which are seated in troffers.  Original ballasts have been removed from the troopers.  **Is there a simple test that can be performed without special test equipment?**  The goal is not necessarily gain a quantitive measurement, but to understand if and what frequency bands are impacted.

The issue is not critical (yet), however, I would like to know if there are simple / inexpensive methods to test.   I am seeking tests that can be performed with equipment under $100.   I would think that the most important spectrum to guard are  the cellular and wifi bands: a [UBNT Nanostation](http://ubiquiti%20nanonstation) might be repurposed.

Comment: I would contact the mfg, T8 retrofit usually use a mosfet driver as the heart of the power supply and the manufacturer already has this information, however the RFI will be much less if it is a ballast bypass, if it is a plug and play (keeping the ballast) the original RFI listing of the ballast + & - the driver RFI. Whithout a spectrum analyser it would be difficult to find the frequency.

Comment: Are these going in troffers?  How critical is the EMI issues? What's youur budget?

Comment: @Harper Good question: OP updated to address the questions

Answer (score 1):

A FM radio tuned to a weak station may indicate if there is interference, and tuning it to a frequency with no station may also work as detector. Muting must be switched off. An AM radio can likewise detect interference in lower frequency ranges.

LED bulbs/lights often are a big source of problems concerning RFI. Due to the pulse width modulation in the LED power supply, a wide frequency range is emitted if no filters are used in the LED electronic. There are cheap LED bulbs with a simple RC- network as power supply resulting in less interference, but they flicker - visible by quickly moving a finger or pen up and down in front of them.

When shopping LED bulbs, a RFI test can be performed with the radio (and earphones as antenna) that comes with many smart phones, but a muting switch is often missing.
When purchased via Internet, LED bulbs can be tested at home and sent back if they fail.